# jsTree: how to obtain metadata of nodes while traversing the tree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I've seen many answers of obtaining node metadata when the node is selected (select_node binding), but what I'm trying to achieve is first to obtain the children from a node and then  iterate through them to obtain their metadata. This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ps0604/G789k/347/) attempts to do that. What's wrong with this code?

this is the HTML:

```
<form>
    <input value="List Nodes Metadata" type="button" onclick="listNodesMetadata();" />
</form>

<div id="treediv" />
```

and this is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var tree = [ { "data" : "Node1", metadata: { x: "x1"  }, "attr":{"rel":"rel1",  "id" : "id1"} },
             { "data" : "Node2", metadata: { x: "x2"  },  "attr":{"rel":"rel2",  "id" : "id2"} },
             { "data" : "Node3", metadata: { x: "x3"  }, "attr":{"rel":"rel3",  "id" : "id3"} }
         ];

  $("#treediv").jstree({
            "json_data" : { "data" : tree },
            "plugins" : [ "json_data", "ui", "crrm", "types" ]
    });

});  


function listNodesMetadata(){

    var nodes = jQuery.jstree._reference("#treediv")._get_children(-1);
    var len = nodes.length;

    for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
        alert ( i + " " + nodes[i].data('x') );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G789k/354/). For each child obtain the id, use the find function to obtain the jsTree node, and then from the node access the metadata using the data function.

```
var nodes = jQuery.jstree._reference("#treediv")._get_children(-1);
var len = nodes.length;

for (var i=0;i<len;i++) {
    var node = $('#treediv').find("[id='" + nodes[i].id + "']");
    alert ( nodes[i].id + " " + node.data('x') );
}
```